# XSLT - Getting data from a similarly named sibling using data from the first

Tags: xslt

I am an XSLT newb whose learning by doing. I've managed to do some easier choose when, for each loops but don't understand what is required to do my next aim.
Here is a sample of the input xml.

What I am looking to do is where the  of  is Board, look at the value of  (in the example below its B). Since B means bottom I then want to look at the sibling component where the value of  is EdgeBottom, and return the value of  from this sibling component.

Note that  could be TBLR or any combination of those options, and I want to pull the Material details from each corresponding Component.

I will be outputting into a table but once I get the idea of how it can be done I can muck about this with.  Please excuse any terminology errors above, and the lack of any non-working code examples. Many thanks.

```
<Report schema="1.0">
    <Item id="74" name="cabinet">
        <VSection id="0" vsection="main">
            <HSection id="3">
                <Component id="2" idfull="07400302">
                    <DisplayName>EdgeBottom</DisplayName>
                    <Category>Edging</Category>
                    <Brand>Edging</Brand>
                    <Color>Edging</Color>
                    <Material>0.4mm Edging</Material>
                </Component>
                <Component id="1" idfull="07400301">
                    <DisplayName>Board</DisplayName>
                    <Category>Carcass</Category>
                    <Brand>Laminate</Brand>
                    <Color>White</Color>
                    <Material>16White</Material>
                    <Edging>B</Edging>
                    <IsEdgedOnTop>No</IsEdgedOnTop>
                    <IsEdgedOnRight>No</IsEdgedOnRight>
                    <IsEdgedOnBottom>Yes</IsEdgedOnBottom>
                    <IsEdgedOnLeft>No</IsEdgedOnLeft>
                    <EdgeMatTop>0.4mm</EdgeMatTop>
                    <EdgeMatRight>0.4mm</EdgeMatRight>
                    <EdgeMatBottom>0.4mm</EdgeMatBottom>
                    <EdgeMatLeft>0.4mm</EdgeMatLeft>
                </Component>
            </HSection>
        </VSection>
    </Item>
    <DocumentProperties>
    </DocumentProperties>
</Report>
```

Comment: How do we know that `B` equates to `EdgeBottom`? That important rule is missing from your description.

Comment: You've been learning by doing - where is the XSLT that you've already done?

Comment: @ABach Sorry, TBLR stands for Top, Bottom, Left, Right. If the <Edging> was TR I'd need to pull the info from the component where the <DisplayName> value was EdgeTop and EdgeRight.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I didnt post any code as I haven't managed to pull anything from the other component. I'm happy to post other stuff I've worked out, but its not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you were positioned on a 'Board' component....

```
<xsl:template match="Component[DisplayName='Board']">
```

Then you could use the **preceding-sibling** axis to get the **Component** element using a series of **xsl:if** conditions, like so:

```
  <xsl:if test="contains(Edging,  'B')">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::Component[DisplayName='EdgeBottom']"/>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:if test="contains(Edging,  'T')">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::Component[DisplayName='EdgeTop']"/>
  </xsl:if>
```

Then you could just have a template where you output the value for the 'Edging' component. For example

```
<xsl:template match="Component[Category='Edging']">
   <edging>
      <xsl:value-of select="Material" />
   </edging>
</xsl:template>
```

If you wanted to simplify things, the **xsl:if** conditions could be combined into one single statement. If the possible values of the edging are indeed "EdgeTop", "EdgeBottom", "EdgeLeft" and "EdgeRight" then the fifth character of each of these are obviously "T", "B", "L" and "R" and so can be checked directly against the current component, like so...

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="preceding-sibling::Component
                [contains(current()/Edging, substring(DisplayName, 5, 1))]"/>
```

Here is a sample XSLT which demonstrates this in action...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Component[DisplayName='Board']" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Component[DisplayName='Board']">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::Component[contains(current()/Edging, substring(DisplayName, 5, 1))]"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Component[Category='Edging']">
      <edging>
         <xsl:value-of select="Material" />
      </edging>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that if the **Component** element could be a following sibling, not just a preceding one, then try this expression instead:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
     select="../Component
               [Category='Edging']
               [contains(current()/Edging, substring(DisplayName, 5, 1))]"/>
```

Comment: Great answer, especially given the lack of insight from the question.

Comment: Thank you very much. Not only does it work but I understand what you were doing too. I only had to make some slight changes to suit the situation (eg change select="//Component to select="../Component so it didnt go back to the root).  One thing I came across was a situation where the Component elements were both preceding and following. I ended up creating 2 <apply template> lines, 1 that uses preceding-sibling and one that uses following-sibling. It gives me the right output, but is it ok to do this?

Comment: That is OK to do, although you should be able to `<xsl:apply-templates select="../Component` too in this case, as long as you add an expression to exclude the current component. I did notice a problem with the last code sample in my question in this respect, but have amended it to hopefully work correctly.

Comment: Ahh, I did notice the last sample worked when there was preceding siblings, but broke when there were both preceding and following.  That updated sample works sweet. Thanks again @TimC.